# How are updates handled with Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Do you have to write update statements with Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Kinda. You can use it somewhat like an ORM in that you can update your in-memory data model, and then execute a dynamically generated UPDATE statement when you submit changes. For example:

```
using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataConext())
{
     db.Clients.First().Salary = 50000;
}
```

does not perform an update, but

```
using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataConext())
{
     db.Clients.First().Salary = 50000;
     db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

does.

Comment: I have found that there is an attach error at times, so db.Clients.Attach(a) is needed.  I found this to be an issue when looping through a list to change values.

Comment: James, can you post some example code where this might be necessary?